# calibre - how to upload my highlights online?

Tags: kindle, calibre

I'm using calibre to upload books to my kindle (via usb). So my amazon account is not aware of my books.

I want to be able to view my highlights and comments online somehow. 
Since my books are not connected to my amazon account, they do not appear in the link https://read.amazon.com/notebook.

Is there any way to upload the notes and highlights automatically to some online service?

Or even not automatically? I've tried the `Fetch Annotations` in calibre, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found this site: https://my.clippings.io

It allows you to upload a file named `my clippings` which is downloadable through the `fetch annotations` button in calibre. I found this file in my library after performing the fetch.